# Can an http get request's parameter be a url?

Tags: http, get, httprequest, query-string, http-get

We've got a client that would like to get a response from our server that would look something like that:

```
http://www.clientDomain.com/tmp?first=a&second=b&link=$$http://www.otherDomain.com/tmp?third=c&forth=d$$
```

The client doesn't want the link parameter to be encoded.

As far as I'm aware, this is an illegal parameter, that may seems like one is trying to confuse a web server or a router, yet I could not find any documentation to support that. I didn't find any relevant info in the http protocol documentations.

Is that really an illegal parameter? Can you please refer me to a relevant documentation?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You'll need to escape some of the characters, other than that, it should just work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encode URL in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the URL Encoding section here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string